# Construct postal address from individual components

Tags: android

I have an object with a bunch of postal address details such as zipcode, street name, home number etc. and i would like to display this as an intelligent string with commas put in place and sections ommited if that detail is not available. Is there a library call in the Android sdk which would let me construct a full postal address string with whatever portions of it i have in my object?

Comment: Try using a StringBuilder.

Comment: Android does have a class that represents an Address: [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a StringBuilder to build the string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(street).append(", ").append(zipCode).append(".");
String output = sb.toString();
```